# How get scroll offset of each component that has a scroll bar?

Tags: android, delphi, scroll, offset, firemonkey

Some people ask me:
**How to get scroll offset of each component that has a scroll bar** and how to get coordinates of some items (maybe TListBoxitem in TListBox) on visible part of component - example for showing TPopup for current item?

```
Popup.Position.X:= ListBox.ItemByIndex(0).Position.X;
Popup.Position.Y:= ListBox.ItemByIndex(0).Position.Y;
```

This code show TPopup on the top-left corner of Item(0) and is visible.

When is visible Item(100) TPopup is not on the top-left corner and is not visible:

```
Popup.Position.X:= ListBox.ItemByIndex(100).Position.X;
Popup.Position.Y:= ListBox.ItemByIndex(100).Position.Y;
```

How make TPopup visible on the top-left corner for each item?

Comment: I'm not sure what's actually meant by this, even with an answer. Can you please edit your question to elaborate what you mean?

Comment: You should invite those people to post their question on Stack Overflow instead of asking you to be their go-between. You can't answer clarifying questions like they can because it's not really your question.

Comment: An example may be used for example to determine the position of TListBoxItem in TListBox (on the visible screen) if the list items greater than the height of TListBox and subsequent display example TPopup for current TListBoxitem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simply (example for TListBox):

```
var
  offsetX, offsetY: single;
begin
  offsetX:= myListBox.ViewportPosition.X;
  offsetY:= myListBox.ViewportPosition.Y;
end;
```

And how make visible TPopup on top-left corner for each items:

```
Popup.Position.X:= ListBox.ItemById(0).Position.X - ListBox.ViewportPosition.X;
Popup.Position.Y:= listBox.ItemById(0).Position.Y - ListBox.ViewportPosition.Y;
.
.
.
Popup.Position.X:= ListBox.ItemById(100).Position.X - ListBox.ViewportPosition.X;
Popup.Position.Y:= listBox.ItemById(100).Position.Y - ListBox.ViewportPosition.Y;
```